# Android app close itself (app with tabs and tabgroup)

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs

I have this code which have always worked until today:

```
            // primo accesso
            Intent previewMessage = new Intent(getParent(), InventarioNoPassword.class);
            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
            finish();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("InventarioNoPassword", previewMessage);
```

When I go into the InventarioNoPassword, the app go but it close itself in about one second.
I don't know why.
I'm working in a tabgroup.
Better: my app is with tab, and one tab is tabgroup. This code is in the first activity launched by the tabgroup.

Answer (score 1):

- use this, or getApplicationContext(), instead of getParent();
- call finish(); after you start the new Activity.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you just go to child activity but no need to **finish** the current Parent activity. If you finish the current parent activity then it's not return back to your Parent from your child. Just remove finish() and try.